# Integrate GTM snippets with AEM pages

Tags: aem, google-tag-manager

Is there any direct way to integrate Google Tag Manager JS snippets in AEM pages ?

The AEM Tools provide only for Google Analytics snippet using cloud services component. But GTM needs ***two*** code snippets on a page, one in `<head>` and one in `<body>` section of the page.

Hard coding the JS snippets in my HTML's is not a good idea.

Comment: Implement a clientlib and make it configurable via page properties and expose these properties via Sling model. This should be a good solution.

Comment: @FlorianSalihovic .. I get your point. But if I go for Page properties and sling model, maybe we can skip the clientlib and just add the snippet on the HTML directly from properties

Comment: You don't want the editors to handle JavaScript in page properties. This is application specific code and should be handled with care.

Answer (score 0):

GTM scripts is based on website specific tracking. So you can create sitelevel configurations for GTM containerID(think for future) and add header footer script in page component with dynamic containerID that you can configure in site level config so that it will be available across all pages.